# Jacoco report 0% coverage on apache project run on intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, jacoco-plugin

I have written some unit tests for this project and got jacoco to work producing the reports but the coverage is 0% on every module.I'm working on intellij on Windows but i didn't read that the apache project OpenJpa is system dependant , so it should not be the problem.

Here the main pom.xml link : https://github.com/CecBazinga/openJpa/blob/master/pom.xml

Here the pom.xml of the 2 modules in which i have written the unit tests :

https://github.com/CecBazinga/openJpa/blob/master/openjpa-jdbc/pom.xml

https://github.com/CecBazinga/openJpa/blob/master/openjpa-lib/pom.xml

And here the pom.xml of the empty module in which jacoco creates the reports:

https://github.com/CecBazinga/openJpa/blob/master/tests/pom.xml

Unit tests work fine but i have no idea why jacoco doesn't register their coverages.
Hope you can help, good day all!

Comment: Do other code coverage engines show the same behaviour?

Comment: i'm using jsut jacoco i don't know how to use different coverage engines.I use sonar cloud too but i think it relies on jacoco reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out after some researching/intuition that in pom.xml were missing some surefire plugin dependencies.I integreted them and now it works fine!